# Deploy a docker container on AWS ECS has failed

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy a docker container on AWS ECS. I did below steps:

I have pushed a postgres DB image and myapp image from docker hub to ECR.
Created ECS cluster, created Task Definition plus added Postgres container, and created the service. I have verified DB is up & running.

In the same cluster I have created another Task Definition plus added myapp container. Here I provided DATABASE_ENDPOINT as ec2 public DNS and created the service. It does not work and there are no DB connection related error. I have noticed ConnectionResetError in the Events log.

What could be the issue? Is the DATABASE_ENDPOINT URI correct?

Comment: What do the ECS logs say for that task/container when you launch it?

Comment: CloudWatch logs shows the same error..ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Comment: btw, a lot of calls for internal python scripts like runtime.py, start.py etc.. after ConnectionResetError error message.

Comment: To achieve communication between different tasks, you'll need to enable [Service Discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-tasks-services-communication/) first. Note that it's highly recommended to use RDS for data persistence.

Comment: I tried using RDS Postgres instance. It keep complaining about postgres invalid URL.